# What is the port for SolAdmin?

Tags: solace

I would like to use SolAdmin to configure my Solace VMR, what is the default admin port to use in SolAdmin when connecting to a Solace VMR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default SolAdmin port for a VMR is port 8080.

You can verify this by looking at the configuration of the SEMP service via the CLI.

```
solace> show service

...

Service  TP  S C R VRF   MsgVpn          Port  A O Failed Reason
-------- --- ----- ----- --------------- ----- --- ---------------------------
SEMP     TCP N - - Mgmt                   8080 U U
```

Comment: All of the VMR defaults are also listed online here: http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/vmr-configuration-defaults/. Again in this documentation, the SolAdmin port is the same as the SEMP port.